# What I need to write in JoinColumn?

Tags: java, hibernate

Sorry for my question. Really can`t understand my mistake. 
I have a Hibernate relations between two classes but when I run it logs give me this error:

> org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference
>        an unknown target entity property: model.pilgi.Pilgi.PilgiDocument in model.pilgi_doc.PilgiDocument.pilgi

Code of the fisrt class PilgiDocument:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pilgi_document")
public class PilgiDocument {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column
    private BigInteger pdocument_id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "PilgiDocument")
    private List<Pilgi> pilgi = new ArrayList();
```

Pilgi class is here:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pilgi")
public class Pilgi {


    @JoinColumn(name = "pilga")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private PilgiDocument pdocument_id;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error your have says that Hibernate doesn't find the `PilgiDocument` attribute in the class Pilgi: you don't have it but you have a pdocument_id property, that is an instance of `PilgiDocument`

In your PilgiDodument class, what you need to write is :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pilgi_document")
public class PilgiDocument {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column
private BigInteger pdocument_id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "pdocument_id")
private List<Pilgi> pilgi = new ArrayList();
```

You indicate the name of the attribute of your `Pilgi` class that represent the `PilgiDocument` attribute

In your Pilgi class, you need to write, in your `@JoinColumn` the name of the database column used as your foreign key for your PilgiDocument

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if this works fine. Thanks